create object type based on base type member function return value
I am implementing a loadbalancer that should choose balancing strategy based on some logic:
class LoadBalancer{
public: 
      bool get_backend_cpu_info(){// some complicate logic involve member backends b }
      static void create(){
         if successfully get_backend_cpu_info():
               use LoadBalancerCPU.choose_backend()
          else
               use LoadBalancerRoundRobin.choose_backend()
      }
      choose_backend(){// depends on which type of loadbalancer we are using}
private:
     vector<backends> b;
};

In c++ ,A straightforward forward approache is to make choose_backend a virtual function to get runtime polymorphism. However, the method get_backend_cpu_info() is also complicated process and need access to class member backends, which means I have to create the class itself before calling get_backend_cpu_info() . A another approch is to use factory method but still the  get_backend_cpu_info() method need access to members before object creation. What is a good design pattern or class relationship in my case ???? This question is language independent and I 'm just using C++ as a example.
I expect a good design pattern or class relationship design, prefereably with C++ code

I'm not sure if I understand you fully, but why don't you just make a function which will choose the appropriate function for you (or chose in the constructor) and you end up with a function pointer and store that as a member in your object. Then you can just blindly call that function and you are done.

@simre because different chooser function access different data member. say choose_fun1() will access  member m1,m2,m3, choose_fun2(_) will access m2,m4, m5. Then i have to store all members m1-m5 in class LoadBalancer, inefiiciency!
